# How to calculate expectation value

Tags: algorithm, probability

I am stuck in a problem of expectation value.

I have been given a undirected graph with different connected components. The ith component has x[i] elements in it. Both the number of connected components and set x are given. Once you choose a node, all the nodes connected to that node get marked.

```
So overall we have to do something like this:
1. Pick any node which is not marked.
2. Mark all the nodes of the connected component, which contains node chosen in step 1.
repeat process 1, 2 until you mark a specific code.
```

What is expectation value of number of choices we have to make until desired node is marked.

I can calculate the expectation value by brute force, but is there any other efficient method to calculate it?

Comment: please clarify: When you say "all the nodes connected to it" in step 2, is that all its immediate neighbors, or all the nodes in its component?

Comment: @ChrisBeck All the nodes in its component.

Comment: @user3518014 Can you please suggest the number of steps in which you  want to do this, so that I can get an idea what you are considering brute force and what efficient?

Comment: @Dante. I am looking for linear solution. But a  nlog(n) sloution will also work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let `U_i` be a random variable equal to 1 if the ith component is chosen before the target component (and zero otherwise).

The number of choices is therefore given by `sum U_i`.  (Possibly + 1 if finding it the first time counts as 1 choice).

So the expected value of this random variable is given by `sum E(U_i)` by the linearity of expectation.

Now, `E(U_i) = 0 * P(U_i == 0) + 1 * P(U_i==1) = P(U_i==1)` so all we have to do is calculate the probability that the ith component is chosen before the target.

The ith component has x[i] members, while the target has x[t] members.

All that is important is which of these x[i]+x[t] nodes is the first to be selected at random, so there is a probability of `x[i]/(x[i]+x[t])` that the first selected is in component i.

So we conclude:

```
P(U_i==1) = x[i]/(x[i]+x[t])

E(number of choices) = sum_(i != t) x[i]/(x[i]+x[t])
```

(Possibly + 1 depending on the problem definition)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @Peter